# how to calculate equivalent resistance of a circuit

Tags: resistance

[image]

R2=100 ohm , R3=150ohm  , R4=220ohm  , R6=330ohm

I calculate equivalent resistance like this

150*100/150+100=60 ohm

220*330/220+330=132 ohm

60+132=192 ohm

can you tell me whether it true or wrong?

Comment: R3 is not parallel with R2. R3 is in parallel with R2+(R4||R6)

Comment: As seen from source terminals? In that case it'd be R3 || (R2 + (R4 || R6))

Answer (score 4):

This only looks difficult because of the layout.
If you would take the time to redraw it you could see that this is very simple to solve.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fF01mG.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Answer (score 2):

R4 and R6 are in paralell, so calculate it first. Then, do the series with R2, and finally, the paralell with R3. So:

```
1/Ra = 1/R4 + 1/R6
Ra = (R4*R6)/(R4 + R6)
Rb = Ra + R2
Rtotal = (Rb*R3)/(Rb + R3)
```